# Can spring inject sample bean twice with different parameterization?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Consider a code:

```
public class MyProcessor<T extends GenericData> implements ProcessorInterface<T> {

    @Autowired
    private List<SomeCriteria<T>> criterias;

    @Override
    public long calculate(T data) {
        long result = 0;
        for (SomeCriteria c : criterias) {
            result += c.calculate(data);                        
        }
        return long;         
    }
}
```

So the difference only in `SomeCriteria` implementation and `GenericData`. E.g. for one `GenericData` there are several 
`SomeCriteria`. So if there are 3 `GenericData` is it possible to write a code like that:

```
public DataService {
    @Autowire
    private MyProcessor<DataOne> processorOne;
    @Autowire
    private MyProcessor<DataTwo> processorTwo;
    @Autowire
    private MyProcessor<DataThree> processorThree;
}
```

Without writing implementation for processor each time?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. As of Spring 4.0 you can do thing such as

```
@Autowired
private Store<String> s1; // Injects the stringStore bean

@Autowired
private Store<Integer> s2; // Injects the integerStore bean
```

The example above was copied from the [Spring Framework 4.0 and Java Generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics) blog post by [Phil Webb](https://spring.io/team/pwebb) on the Spring web site. Please read it for more details.

Comment: I see, but if `Store<T>` has dependecies like `Item<T>`, will Spring inject `Item<Sring>` into Store when Store autowired like `@Autowired Store<String>`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Qualifier` annotation for create more than one bean of the same type. I hope this will helpfull to you.

```
public DataService {
    @Qualifier
    private MyProcessor<DataOne> processorOne;
    @Qualifier
    private MyProcessor<DataTwo> processorTwo;
   }
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use the `@Qualifier` annotation to get generic support, see my answer (or preferably read the blog post about [Spring Framework 4.0 and Java Generics](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics).